# C# windows application trim character after dot I want only display one character

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to trim this column character. For example this is the column data 55.30000000000000004. Now want to display data 55.3 like this. Could you help me give simple C# windows application code?

Comment: `Math.Round` - please use google before asking on here.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your
way arround here. Also I suggest you check how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically how to create minimal, complete and verifiable examples. 
These guidelines will help you get better answers in the future. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      double val = 55.30000000000000004;
      Console.WriteLine(string.format("Rounded val: {0}", Math.Round(val)));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  Code below shows two ways to do this.  The format parameter is "0.0", which causes the number to be converted to string, showing one decimal.

For additional format options see:

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double val = 55.30000000000000004;

        string strVal=val.ToString("0.0");
        Console.WriteLine("Formatted value (a): " + strVal);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Formatted value (b): {0:0.0}", val));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output:

Formatted value (a): 55.3
Formatted value (b): 55.3